# Import data from a formatted text file into a dataset

Tags: import, dataset, column

As you can see from the picture, it's a txt. file, and when I use Import, lot's of different type of data stored in one column, I want to devide them into different columns. For example: the 1st column is the "USAF" and the numbers below it, the 2nd is the "WBAN" and the numbers below it,  the 3rd is the "STATION NAME" and the names below it... I've tried to store the txt. file into csv. and file, but it still showed in this way.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Share your original data with us. We can't give good suggestions without trying something out ourselves. What are the record separators in the text file? Have you tried importing as `"Table"` rather than `"Data"`?

Comment: I couldn't find the hyperlink of the file. And the separators in the text file should be space.

Comment: Try something like `Import["yourfilename", "Table", "HeaderLines" -> 1, "IgnoreEmptyLines" -> True, FieldSeparators -> {" ", "\t"}] // Dataset` instead like MarcoB suggests.

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't devide the dataset into more columns. And I have already found the source file that is divided into columns. I will abandon the reference to this file and use the new one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the resource function
[ImportCSVToDataset](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ImportCSVToDataset):

```
ResourceFunction["ImportCSVToDataset"]["~/Downloads/noaa-stations.txt", "TSV"]
```

Here is an example with a text file data similar to the one in the images you posted:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, thank you, that might be a useful way, but I forgot the hyperlink of the file. Fortunately, I got the new source with different columns. And I will use that one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the function SemanticImport. Look at the options this function has to adapt to your particular case: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SemanticImport.html

Comment: You might wish to demonstrate.

Comment: I flagged this post as "non-answer".